# Puppet SSL connection issue

Tags: ssl, puppet

#### puppet version 2.6.6

I intermittently see SSL connection errors similar to the following on puppet agents:

```
Could not evaluate: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 
read server hello A Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://...: 
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

or:

```
Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect 
SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

I've found several posts which describe this as being potentially due to TLS handshake timeout between master and agent but am not clear where this can be configured if indeed it is the problem.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Kind regards, Andrew Eells

Answer (score 4):

So firstly an apology: some of the older error messages for SSL in Puppet suck. We used to pass through the Ruby SSL errors directly and not catch and raise the right things. This is a lot better in 2.7.x and later.

The issue here is most likely time. If your master and client aren't in sync time-wise then SSL will fail. This isn't a Puppet requirement - this is just how SSL works. This [MS KB has a good description of the SSL handshake process](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257591).

The best way to address this is to ensure the time on the master and client are in sync and you can do this by running NTP (which you can also manage with Puppet using [our NTP module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/ntp)).

Hope that helps and if you have further issues we have an IRC channel on Freenode #puppet and a Puppet mailing list with a lot of helpful folks!

Comment: I couldn't post more than two links - so our mailing list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/puppet-users).

Comment: Hello James @jamtur01, thanks for your response.

Both master and agent(s) are already running NTP - comes out of the box with Amazon EC2 by the looks of it - so I'm not convinced there isn't another problem here.

But without some further diagnostics I can't add much to the conversation. Thankfully, it's not too frequent an occurrence but I'll post to the mailing list if I can add something more...

Thanks again and kind regards,

Drew

Comment: This was completely solved for me (both Debian and CentOS) by losing the default puppetmaster config (running webrick as the webserver). On Debian there is an puppetmaster-passenger in squeeze backports or current, which completely solved everything just by installation. On CentOS these instructions and the linked github repo did the job for me: http://barriebremner.com/geek/passenger_puppet.html